# how to make next link for pagination

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I am new to jsp in my jsp i have

href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page=1" target="_blank">Next On First Page

href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page=1" target="_blank">Next On 2nd Page

href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page=1" target="_blank">Next On 3rd Page

href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page=1" target="_blank">Next On 4rth Page

However , i want this link on every page
**Requirement :**
Next

So i applied for-each loop on  tag

```
 <c:forEach items="${i}" var="i">
     <a href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page='${i+1}'" target="_blank">Next</a>    
</c:forEach>
```

${i} : Its an attribute from my controller with int i=0;
However , compiler is saying it cant interate on "i"

How can i fix that? I am doing Pagination

Comment: Why isn't `<a href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page='${i+1}'" target="_blank">Next</a>` enough?  You want more than one next link to show on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `userdata` is your controller.  Make the controller set the *next* page's id, not the current one's, and name it something better than `i`, like `nextPageID`.

So in the controller, take the current id received in the request parameter `page`, if any, and add one to it, and set it in the request attribute `nextPageID`. I guess if no page id was received, the next id would 2.  Then in your JSP:

```
<a href="${mainUrl}/userdata?page='${nextPageID}'" target="_blank">Next</a>
```

Because if you are adding one in the JSP, how do you know this isn't the last page?  Keep the logic part in the controller. The controller will presumably know which number is the last page.

BTW, you obviously cannot iterate on a simple int; Iteration means traversing over an array or list.

Comment: how i can send back my nextPageID. to the controller?

Comment: That's what `?page=` is doing, right? That tells the controller which page is being requested. I'm assuming you know how to use request.getParameter and how to parse a string into an int.

Comment: ya thats true "?page=" is doing same. i know hw to use request.getParameter but why do i need to parse a string into int?

Comment: How will you add 1 to it if its a string? Integer.parseInt(str)